# Copy n words in a single string using strcat

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, strcat

How can i copy n different words in a single string using strcat? This is my code but doesn't work. The size of the single words is 40. `arr` contain the different words and `fin` is my final string.

```
char *cat(char **arr,int n){
    int i;
    char *fin;
    fin = malloc(n*40);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        strcat(arr[i],fin);
    }
    return fin;
}
```

Comment: exchange arg order : `strcat(fin, arr[i]);`

Comment: Ooh right!! But now i have strange character at the beginning of the string. Moreover it is all joined without spaces, how can i add them between each word?

Comment: Ok i solved the spaces problem but i still have 3 strange character at the beginning of the string each execution

Comment: You do not terminate `fin` after allocating it. The memory allocated by `malloc` doest not contain any defined values. It's up to you to initialize it properly. In your case a simple `fin[0]=0;` will do.

Comment: Thank you, now it works, but can you explain me why i have to initialize in this way? Isn't it a "char *" fin? Why i have to initialize fin[0] = 0?

Comment: In C character strings have to be terminated with a 0 byte. Any function dealing with strings expect this to be true. The memory where `*fin` points to does not necessarily contain a 0 byte. Therefore all other bytes are treated to be part of your string. You can initlize it via `fin[0]=0` or `*fin=0` which is exactly the same.

Comment: Ok got it, but if that's the problem did i not have to put the '\0' character at the end? Why in this case at the beginning?

Comment: The beginning actually is the end of the string. When you start, you want to have a string with length 0 and then append more strings at the end. Wrinting 0 to the first byte is how you make the string an empty string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to concatenate the strings from *arr* info *fin* you need to reverse the order of argument, so replace

> ```
> strcat(arr[i],fin);
> ```

by

```
strcat(fin, arr[i]);
```

because the first argument is the destination  and the second the source.

But that suppose to initialize *fin* to be an empty string, so before the loop do

```
*fin = 0;
```

> The size of the single words is 40

warning if you speak about the length rather than the size including the terminating null character you need to allocate one more :

```
fin = malloc(n*40 + 1);
```

---

From your remark :

> Moreover it is all joined without space how can i add them between each word?

if you want to add a space you need to allocate more and to explicitly add your space, can be :

```
fin = malloc(n*41+1);
*fin = 0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    strcat(fin, arr[i]);
    strcat(fin, " ");
}
```

note if *n* large *strcat* search the end of *fin* which is more and more long, better to save the pointer to the end and use *strcpy*, for instance :

```
char * fin = malloc(n*41+1);

if (n == 0) {
  *fin = 0;
}
else {
  char * p = fin;

  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    strcpy(p, arr[i]);
    p += strlen(p) + 1;
    p[-1]  = ' ';
  }
  p[-1]  = 0;
}
return fin;
```